# Is there any algorithm that is not dependent upon n (size of inputs)?

Tags: algorithm, input, time, size, time-complexity

I was just curious yet google couldn't help me much with this.
Does there exist any algorithm which doesn't depend on size of inputs? Like, whose time complexity won't depend on n?

Comment: Find the value of the first element of a given array.

Comment: Yes, an algorithm that does not use any input would not depend on the size of the input.

Comment: Return the smaller of the first two elements.

Comment: "Algorithm" is a broad term here. I could swap 2 bits, which is constant time.

Comment: A perfect hash function can do constant time lookups.

Comment: Did you look for "constant time algorithm" (keywords are everything)? If not, that would be a good starting point. Unfortunately too broad (too many possible answers) for [so] (as per [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)), but you already have a few examples.

Comment: Hashing and comparing (returning the smaller of the first two elements of an array) doesnt run in constant time. They will run in defferent time depending if you are hasing/comparing integers, longs, strings of length up to 10000 or 1Gb files.

Comment: Return a random element (assuming equal time to access any element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any constant time algorithm (hashing, array lookup and adding to or removing from the front of a List are examples) do not depend on the size of inputs.

Comment: We always say "constant time", but if someone wants to get REALLY pedantic, they can argue that it could depend on the number of bits in the data structure being used. Only so many bits can be processed in one operation, but as the data gets larger, the operations are more like O(n) in the number of bits. Super pedantic, maybe not completely correct, I know. This question is very broad.

Comment: Some algorithms do not process the entire data structure but only, for example, look up one location in memory and perform the operations on it.  These are truly constant time.  Your comment isn't entirely correct.

Comment: I gathered I'd get some flak for it :) Agreed, *some* algorithms do that (like an algorithm to flip 1 bit). Many of the "constant" time algorithms being listed here, though, don't necessarily operate like that.

Comment: Hashing doesnt run in constant time, computing the hash function takes usually O(n) respect to the size of the key.

Comment: @AndyG: If you're REALLY pedantic, you define yourself a theoretical computation model and define run time as the number of primitive operations that an algorithm would need to solve a task in that model.  Now one of the most commonly used (and often implicitely assumed) models is the [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) model, where arithmetic operations on a word are primitive. Since memory adresses are also represented as words, that means that for every data structure of size proportional to `n` that is located in your memory, `n` *really* fits into `O(1)` words.

Comment: This is also true in reality. I can say with some confidence that you will never feel the need to store data of size `n`, where `n` can not be represented by an 512-bit integer. Even if you only needed one bit for every element to store it, the number of bits would exceed the number of atoms in the universe, so where in hell would you store this data structure? :) This is why even if you're pedantic, constant time in this sense *is* constant time (even if the constant factor might be large).

Answer (score 0):

There are many, even practical ones:

Say you need to return the smallest element from a data set. You know your list is already sorted, so you return the first element.